# Not showing the map data - Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I know that this problem has been consulted before, but no answer gives me a solution.
I want to use Xamarin.Form.Maps and I can not see the map. I have tried with a simple application of mine and with the WorkingWithMaps example

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/

In both tests I get the same attached image:

[From my Samsung device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFkkR.png)

I have tested on my Samsung device and emulator.
I have already successfully created my Google Maps API v2 key from the suggested link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=vswin

I do not get compilation errors.
I have also modified my Android manifest as indicated. In the case of WorkingWithMaps everything is set. I have also enabled the necessary permissions.
I have updated Visual Studio, Nugets and the Google Play Services app ...
And, honestly, I do not know what else to do ...
Any help, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the output log for any messages related to mapping?

Comment: mmmm At this time I can only test with an emulator and this warning tells me:  

14212]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/async/AsyncSocketServer.cpp:99:Error when accepting host connectionError message: Unknown error  
Later, I'll be able to test with my device to see if it shows the same error.  
Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Yes, off course... 
At one point I changed the name of the project in Google Developer Console, but I never generated the key again.
Thank you very much, Jason..
Best Regards!